# CRM 2013-Azure Integration issue

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm-2013

We are facing problem in CRM 2013-Azure Integration.

Below lines explains the CRM 2013 –Azure integration.
1.Plugin will read the data from CRM record and send the data to Azure Service Bus Queue.
2.Azure worker role will read the data from service bus queue and send it to WCF service which will insert/update the data in Azure DB.

When we call the send method to send the data to service bus queue we are getting “channel open did not complete within the specified timeout” error. Below is the code snippet of Azure Service Bus call.

```
Uri runtimeUri = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["schemaName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceNamespace"], string.Empty);
MessagingFactory mf = MessagingFactory.Create(runtimeUri,TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sharedAccessKey"]));
sendClient = mf.CreateQueueClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queuePath"]);
BrokeredMessage helloMessage = new BrokeredMessage(list of CRM data));
helloMessage.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
sendClient.Send(helloMessage);
```

But when we do the same operation from local(Outside CRM) it is working fine. Please suggest us some solution if you have any.